# Entity Framework trying to insert parent object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**The Problem**

I'm using Entity Framework to add a complex object model to the database. I'm encountering an issue where I try to insert a child object that EF is also trying to insert the parent object, which is causing an integrity issue in the database.

**Explanation**

For my example, let's assume we have two tables:

1. Shop
2. ShopPerformance

A Shop can have many ShopPerformance entries, the ShopPerformance must have a Shop, and the Shop record already exists in the database (so EF should be leaving it alone and focusing on the ShopPerformance).

In my example, I am attempting to add the ShopPerformance only (in this case the instance of ShopPerformance is called "performance":

```
this.db.Entry(performance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
this.db.SaveChanges();
```

When I call SaveChanges(), EF is trying to insert the Shop as well, which causes a constraint error in the database as it has constraints to prevent duplicate entries (based on the shop's name).

**Things I've Tried**

I've tried setting the Shop property in ShopPerformance to null to stop EF from doing things I don't want to do (it still has the ShopID as a separate property). First I tried:

```
Shop theShop = performance.Shop;
performance.Shop = null;
this.db.Entry(performance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
this.db.SaveChanges();
performance.Shop = theShop;
```

In this scenario, EF somehow re-establishes the link between shop and performance and tries to insert shop again.

Then I tried:

```
Shop theShop = performance.Shop;
this.db.Entry(performance).Entity.Shop = null;
this.db.Entry(performance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
this.db.SaveChanges();
this.db.Entry(performance).Entity.Shop = theShop;
```

This causes null reference exceptions.

**Desired Resolution**

I'm looking for a way to insert my performance object without EF fiddling around with the Shop. This is completely breaking my work right now.

**TL;DR**

I want Entity Framework to Insert/Update ONLY the object I have told it to and none of the related objects. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? In particular would like to see where `performance` came from and how its `Shop` property was added.

Comment: Hi Anthony. The code would be length, but by way of explanation, I parse in a flat file. Then I do a lookup on the name of the shop (which is unique). If it does not exist, I insert it, otherwise I leave it alone. Then I try to insert the performance. I create and populate the EF objects as I'm parsing the flat file. Is this enough information?

Answer (score 5):

You are working with disconnected object, both `performance` and `performance.Shop` are entities that are not tracked by EF, and EF has no idea what is the status of `performance.Shop`.

When adding new `performance` with existing `performance.Shop`, EF doesn't know that `performance.Shop` is an existing entity, and EF will mark all un-tracked objects in the graph as `Added` too.

> The reason it happens is that when you use the DbSet.Add method (that
>   is, Screencasts.Add), not only is the state of the root entity marked
>   “Added,” but everything in the graph that the context was not
>   previously aware of is marked Added as well. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

What you need to do is.

- If you have the foreign key association, you could just assign the id instead of the reference.

  ```
  performance.ShopId = performance.Shop.Id;
  performance.Shop = null;
  this.db.Entry(performance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
  this.db.SaveChanges();
  ```
- Or you need to let EF knows that `performance.Shop` is an existing entity by attaching (status = `Unchanged`) it first to the context.

  ```
  this.db.Entry(performance.Shop).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
  this.db.Entry(performance).State = EntityState.Added;
  this.db.SaveChanges();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried:

```
var shop = this.db.shops.Find(id);
shop.Performances.Add(new Performance());

this.db.SaveChanges();
```

Or

```
this.db.performances.Add(new Performance() { ShopId = id });
this.db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Pavel. I've tried creating a new performance object and copying across the properties of the existing one (except for the reference to the shop object), but this still does not work.